# Linux Mint Mate 21.2 ZFS rpool, bpool, and another one - in Caja Sidebar visible - How to get rid of it?

Tags: linux-mint, luks, zfs, mate-desktop

In installed an enrcypted Linux on an separate SSD. In the Install process i choose **ZFS**.

In **Caja** (1.26) i saw these Folder and wonder why i get this, so i just want to get rid of it, because i dont need or want to use it.

[image]

How get rid of it?
I excepted to just hide the Devices via a simple Action.

Warnings i get when i try open the Drives:

```
Error mounting /dev/sdc4 at /media/user/rpool: unknown filesystem type 'zfs_member'
Error mounting /dev/sdc3 at /media/user/rpool: unknown filesystem type 'zfs_member'
```

And the last Device:

```
No key available to unlock device/dev/sdc2
```

$ zpool status -P
pool: bpool
state: ONLINE
config:

```
    NAME                                               STATE     READ WRITE CKSUM
    bpool                                              ONLINE       0     0     0
      /dev/disk/by-partuuid/xxxx-2023-cxxx6-axxb-xxxx  ONLINE       0     0     0
errors: No known data errors

  pool: rpool
 state: ONLINE
config:

    NAME                                                STATE     READ WRITE CKSUM
    rpool                                               ONLINE       0     0     0
      /dev/disk/by-partuuid/xxxxxa-510c-8xx2-bxx7-1xxx  ONLINE       0     0     0
errors: No known data errors
```

Comment: Welcome to Unix & Linux. Please [take the tour](https://unix.stackexchange.com/tour) to learn how Unix & Linux works. Read [how to ask](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/how-to-ask) to improve the quality of your question. Learn what an [on-topic question](https://unix.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic) is. Then take a look to [the help center](https://unix.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic) to see if some _on-topic questions_ are already asked.

Answer (score 0):

**TLDR**: *ZFS is a good tool, but without any knowledge on it (and your question is clear on that), you will go the hard way.*

What your see in *Caja* are not folders but [*ZFS pools*](https://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/lunar/en/man8/zpool.8.html#description) (detailed in the response of the `zpool status` you share).

Your are not supposed to mount those pools, your data & system are already mounted *somewhere else* on *children* of those pools called [*ZFS datasets*](https://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/lunar/en/man8/zfs.8.html#description).

`bpool` is a common name for *boot pool* and `rpool` for *root pool*.

If you run `zfs list -r` you will have more details about the relation between ZFS objects (datasets) and your local filsystem (identified as `MOUNTPOINT`).

Now you need to document yourself a bit more before going further. *Enjoy discovering ZFS* (-;

Comment: okay fair comment but for now, i dont need to use them, and dont want to see them there. its the same thing of unmounted external drives...they are shown in the list but i use them sometimes...the pools i never use yet...

Comment: I'm not aware of a possibility to hide this `¯\_(ツ)_/¯`

Comment: i can switch the browser maybe :)